# Trying to do things the proper Ember.js way... Why won't this work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I have a little box on my page where users can drag files and drop them. It gets a shadow when something is dragged into it and the shadow changes color when it's dropped. The shadow then disappears after a little time passes.

This is what I think my event's code in the view should look like:

```
    App.AddView = Ember.View.extend({
      classNameBindings: ['enter:enter:leave', 'dropped:dropped:leave'],
      enter: false,
      dropped: false,
      text: 'Drag image files here.',
      drop: function(event) {
        this.set('text', 'Thanks!');
        this.set('enter', false);
        this.set('dropped', true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.set('text', 'Drag image files here.');
            this.set('dropped', false);
        }, 3500);
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      },
      [...]
```

However, I am having a couple of problems with this:

1. `this.set('text', [sometext])` doesn't seem to be doing anything, either inside the timeout function or outside of it. However, `$('#drop).text([sometext])` works both inside the timeout function and outside of it. I don't understand why this is.
2. `this.set('dropped', false)` (inside the timeout function) doesn't seem to be removing the "dropped" class from the element, even though `this.set('dropped', true)` (outside the timeout function) does work. Again, I don't understand what's going on here.
3. The adding of the "dropped" class only seems to happen once, even if I wait for it to be removed by the timer and then drag another item into the box. The dragEnter event that adds the "enter" class (and the dragLeave event that removes it ... neither one included in the code above for brevity) seems to be working fine, both before and after an item has been dropped.

What is the proper Ember.js way to change the text and add/remove classes on a view with a timer?

Comment: If you aren't totally familiar with variable scope, I can see how this would cause confusion. Ember sets the context of its methods to `this`, but that timeout you've used has an additional layer of function scope so you will need to provide context (as answered below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this
```

is wrong when you use it in the setTimeOut function because it is bound to the incorrect object. To fix this, you could say

```
setTimeout(function () { blah }.bind(this), interval)
```

or do it the usual way everyone does by assigning

```
var self = this;
setTimeOut(function() { //use self here }, interval )
```

But,  the use of setTimeOut is frowned upon in the world of ember. A better solution would be to use the

```
Ember.run.later
```

which is provided by ember to basically mimic setTimeOut.